# Website address exceeds the margin of the article

Tags: urls

When I use cas.refs.bib to insert my references with sites (url). The website address goes beyond the margin. How do I correct this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6llML.png)

[image]

Look at my code:

```
@misc{EPE17,
  author = {EPE{Empresa de Pesquisa Energética}(Brasil) },
  title  = {Brazilian Energy Balance 2017 Year 2016 / Empresa de Pesquisa
Energética},
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.epe.gov.br/pt/publicacoes-dados-abertos/publicacoes/Balanco-Energetico-Nacional-2017}",
  year = {2017}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problem. We need to know used document class and to problem relevant packages.

Comment: You'll need to add a manual line break most likely. It's difficult to tell without an MWE. but something like `"\url{https://www.epe.gov.br/pt/publicac \\ oes-dados-abertos/publicacoes/Balanco-Energetico-Nacional-2017}"` will probably work. (Note: you may need to add multiple line breaks depending on the length of your URL.)

Comment: I really liked Kenneth Odle's answer. It worked just fine. Thank you! Regarding the response of others I think I need to study more. I am not a programmer, I studied some manuals but everything is very new to me. Thank you all for your attention